# Refering "this" in a lazy initialization supplier?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lazy-initialization

For business decision applications, I run into a lot of cases where I must cache an expensive value with lazy initialization. So I leveraged generics and a Supplier lambda to encapsulate a lazy initialization.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public final class LazyProperty<T> {
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;
    private volatile T value;

    private LazyProperty(Supplier<T> supplier) { 
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }
    public T get() { 
        if (value == null) { 
            synchronized(this) { 
                if (value == null) { 
                    value = supplier.get();
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static <T> LazyProperty<T> forSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) { 
        return new LazyProperty<T>(supplier);
    }
}
```

But I'd like to be able to use this also in cases where I can't initialize a property until after the object is created, because the object can only calculate this property after it is created (usually needing context of itself or other objects). However, this often requires a reference to `this` in the supplier function.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final LazyProperty<BigDecimal> expensiveVal = 
         LazyProperty.forSupplier(() -> calculateExpensiveVal(this));

    public BigDecimal getExpensiveVal() { 
        return expensiveVal.get();
    }
}
```

As long as I can guarantee the LazyProperty's `get()` function is only called after `MyClass` is constructed (via the `getExpensiveVal()` method), there shouldn't be any partial construction issues due to the `this` reference in the supplier, correct?

Comment: I don't necessarily see a problem with this, since `this` refers to `MyClass` and not the lambda.  Were you running into an issue with it, or were you concerned that it was conceptually unsound?

Comment: No I've had no issues, and yeah I was just concerned about this being conceptually unsound. I've always read that references to `this` in initialization or construction is risky because it can expose a partially constructed object. But with functional programming, it makes sense that any lambdas containing references to `this` (referring to MyClass) are harmless unless they are executed at construction.

Comment: Yeah; that's why I don't see an issue here.  You're not using the `expensiveVal` field in a constructor anywhere, so I don't *believe* that you'll run into an issue with that.  You may have an interesting time with the type safety, since you've got to ensure that the `calculateExpensiveVal` will use the correct type you want.

Comment: I've been using this LazyProperty for a week, and I have not gotten any type safety warnings yet using explicit generics (in this case, the `getExpensiveVal()` method would explicitly return a BigDecimal). I haven't tried anything crazy with generic wildcards, extends, etc... in the supplier though.

Comment: This is not a lambda issue. Like with all cases which might look like an escaping `this`, it depends on the code to which the reference is passed (directly or indirectly) and the visibility of the objects in which the reference is stored. Here, the reference is passed implicitly to the lambda metafactory which doesn’t let the reference escape but stores it into the lambda instance which you pass to `forSupplier` which will store it into a `LazyProperty` instance which is returned and stored into the `final` field `expensiveVal`; at this time, none of the instances has been escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will have one Problem which depends on the implementation of method **calculateExpensiveVal**.

1. if **calculateExpensiveVal** calls getExpensiveVal on the passed reference of MyClass you will get NullPointerException.
2. if **calculateExpensiveVal**  creates a thread and pass the reference of MyClass, again you may run into the same problem as point 1.

But if you guarantee *calculateExpensiveVal* is not doing any of the things, then your code stand correct from Thread safety Perspective. MyClass will never be seen partially constructed 
because of the **final** gaurantees provided by the [JMM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)

After saying that even though your ***calculateExpensiveVal** may employ any one or both those points you are only going to have problem in getExpensiveVal method with NullPointerException.

your **lazyProperty.get** method is already thread safe so there woun'd be any problem.

Because you will always see fully constructed Supplier object because of final keyword (***only if you didn't escaped 'this' reference to another thread***) and you already have used volatile for **value** field which takes care of seeing fully constructed **value** object.

Comment: Of course. I probably could have made my abstract example a little more SSCCE-like, but I absolutely agree on both your points and the potential for multi-thread abuse.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the little code you showed you should not have any problems but I would probably write your class like this to be more explicit:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final LazyProperty<BigDecimal> expensiveVal;

    public MyClass() {
        this.expensiveVal = LazyProperty.forSupplier(() -> calculateExpensiveVal(MyClass.this));
    }

    public BigDecimal getExpensiveVal() { 
        return expensiveVal.get();
    }
}
```